# 3rd Party Library importing Error Xcode No known instance method for selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tabbarcontroller

I Really apologise if this is a stupid question.
I want to create an Application which uses a 3rd Party Library infiniteTabController but as i compiled the example/demo code it work perfect but when i import it to my own project the library files are giving errors nameNo known instance method for selector 'previousLocationInView:'

code is here.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
  {
 [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
 if (self.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed) return;
 CGPoint nowPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
 CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self.view];
  _moveX += prevPoint.x - nowPoint.x;
 _moveY += prevPoint.y - nowPoint.y;
 if (!_drag) {
    if (abs(_moveX) > kM13PanDirectionThreshold) {
        if (_panDirection == M13PanGestureRecognizerDirectionVertical) {
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }else {
            _drag = YES;
        }
    }else if (abs(_moveY) > kM13PanDirectionThreshold && _moveY > _moveX) {
        if (_panDirection == M13PanGestureRecognizerDirectionHorizontal) {
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }else {
            _drag = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Prompting Error on This Line.

```
CGPoint prevPoint = [[touches anyObject]previousLocationInView:self.view];
```

Third Party Library Name is M13InfiniteTabController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing some category classes which should be there in the demo project.

Check if there are any other classes in the demo like UIView+Additions.h or something like that.

Thanks